# ng-remote-validate directive multiple Parameters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to to remote validation using ng-remote-validate directive. I am trying to find a way how can i pass multiple values in the request sent to server. currently it is working  with this

```
 <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="feedBackUser.Email" ng-remote-validate="{ '/Setup/CheckEmailExist' : 'uniqueEmail', '/Setup/SelfUserCheck' : 'selfusercheck'}" placeholder="Email" ng-remote-method="GET" class="form-control " required />
```

but i need to pass multiple parameters. I am using ng-remote-Validate Directive
https://github.com/webadvanced/ng-remote-validate

referring to above link I am struggling to figure out how  this code snippet will work

```
$scope.currentPasswordSetArgs = function( val, el, attrs, ngModel ) {
    return { value: val, otherData: attrs.otherData };
};
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Did you consider to use the in-build solution of asyncValidators from ngModelController for this use-case?
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Comment: From within currentPasswordSetArgs, why can't you access your "otherData"? Something like "otherData: $scope.model.otherData" should work, right?

Answer (score -1):

you could use an existing variable in data-binding.
for example create an array:

```
$scope.myArray =  ['/Setup/CheckEmailExist' : 'uniqueEmail', '/Setup/SelfUserCheck' : 'selfusercheck'];
```

and after that you can use this array in your directives like:

```
ng-remote-validate="myArray"
```

I hope this works!

Comment: ng-model  value will be passed as parameter  for these calls. I am trying to pass another parameter to server side.  currently ng-model value picked up as parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could try the built in asyncValidators of Angularjs.

It would work like this:

```
.directive("emailNotExistingValidation", ["$http", function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope,element,attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            var validation = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                var value = modelValue || viewValue;
                return $http.post("/setup/emailExists", {
                    email: value
                });
            }
            ngModelCtrl.$asyncValidators.emaiNotExisting = validation;
        }
    }
}]);
```

In Action: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpud9627/1/)

Answer (score -1):

I used to solve it using [ng-remote-interceptors](https://github.com/webadvanced/ng-remote-validate/pull/13):

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as formCtrl">
  <form>
    <input ng-remote-validate="{ '/some/path' : 'uniqueness' }" ng-remote-interceptors="formCtrl.ngRemoteEmailInterceptors" type="email" name="email" ... />"
  </form>
</div>
```

In `MyCtrl`:

```
this.ngRemoteEmailInterceptors = {
  request: function(httpOptions) {
    var data = httpOptions.method == 'POST' ? httpOptions.data : httpOptions.params;
    data.id = user.id; // Add/change parameters
    return httpOptions;
  }
}
```